# Why MySQL database not update when I update something in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I've recently setup up a MySQL server and an Apache webserver to test my Mysql Database. But there is a problem. PHP won't update the MySql server, or the MySQL server will not update.

I've even gone back and copied and pasted from W3Schools and this seems to do nothing what so ever. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "form_acceptance";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "UPDATE MyGuests SET Player_name='Doe' WHERE id=2";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
  echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

MySql

```
CREATE DATABASE form_acceptance;
CREATE TABLE form_acceptance (
    PersonID int,
    Player_Name varchar(255),
    Countries varchar(255),
    Username varchar(255),
    Level_and_rank varchar(255),
    Max_BR varchar(255)
);
INSERT INTO form_acceptance (PersonID, Player_Name, Countries, Username, Level_and_rank, Max_BR)
SELECT 'SayByeBye_exe', 'SayByeBye_exe', 'US', '^GYMP^SayByeBye_exe', '12_Luitenant', '4.7';
select * FROM form_exceptance;
```

Nothing seems to work. PHP will not update data into MySql. Why not?

Is it maybe because I am using Linux? Or not?

Comment: ```$sql = "UPDATE MyGuests SET Player_name='Doe' WHERE id=2";``` Did you create MyGuests table?

Comment: No I did not. I've changed it to the table name but still unable to make a difference. But should it show in my code or not?

Comment: Because you don't have any id column in the table. How many records does ```form_acceptance ``` table have? You also have a typo  in this line ```select * FROM form_exceptance;```

Comment: @SaachiTech Yes, how do add records to this table? Sorry, I am quite new the MySQL and SQL altogethor.

Comment: The schema and the code don't match, which makes the whole thing very confusing

Comment: The SQL statement contains the field `id`, but it does not exist in the database table schema. Also, it is rare to mix use of upper and lowercase, along with underscores.

Comment: Use `INSERT` to insert new rows into the table.

Comment: It sounds like you need to read a MySQL tutorial to learn the basics. `INSERT` is for adding new rows, `UPDATE` is for modifying existing rows.

Answer (score -1):

For the query to execute make sure you have at least 2 records in the table

```
$sql = "UPDATE MyGuests SET Player_name='Doe' WHERE id=2";
```

if there is no id with value 2 then the query fails so make sure you check that, I don't see anything else wrong except the typing error at last line

Comment: Hi. I need some help with adding ID's, I just can't see how I can do that.

Comment: To add ID you need to insert it see: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Comment: @Ring_Games_Database_And_Coding | Make sure there are at least 2 record one of them should have an ID with value 2

Answer (score -1):

There is couple error you are having with your setup. You do not have any `MyGuests` table so I assume you want to update the `form_acceptance` table. Then the form_acceptance table doesn't have any `id` column so either we have to add this or use the `PersonID` column. Here is the code snippet to fix your issues.

**First**

Please update your MySQL table creation like this. This will make PersonID as a primary auto incremental column.

```
CREATE DATABASE form_acceptance;
CREATE TABLE form_acceptance (
    PersonID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, //Notice we added NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    Player_Name varchar(255),
    Countries varchar(255),
    Username varchar(255),
    Level_and_rank varchar(255),
    Max_BR varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (`PersonID `)//define PersonId as primary key
);
```

**Second**
Insert a few records

```
INSERT INTO form_acceptance (Player_Name, Countries, Username, Level_and_rank, Max_BR)
Values('Player_Name1', 'US', 'Username`', '12_Luitenant', '4.7'),
('Player_Name2', 'US', 'Username2', '12_Luitenant', '4.7');
select * FROM form_acceptance;//Will show you 2 records having PersonID 1 and 2
```

Now fix your update query

```
<?php
$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "form_acceptance";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "UPDATE form_acceptance SET Player_name='Doe' WHERE PersonID=2";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
  echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

This will successfully update the record of the second row where PersonID is 2.

Comment: Since the OP's owner is new to MySQL, I would like to add some comments of mine. The primary key are set to be `auto_increment` and hence there will be no inserting the `PersonID` while we inserting data with the query from the second part.